# How to install PostgreSQL's pg gem on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL's pg gem for Ruby.

I issued the following command:

```
gem install pg
```

I installed Ruby 1.9.2 using RVM.

The above command shows me the following error.

The error is :

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing pg:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-preview3/bin/ruby extconf.rb

checking for pg_config... yes
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)

*** extconf.rb failed ***

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir
 --ruby=/home/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-preview3/bin/ruby
 --with-pg
 --without-pg
 --with-pg-config
 --without-pg-config
 --with-pg-dir
 --without-pg-dir
 --with-pg-include
 --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
 --with-pg-lib
 --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
 --enable-static-build
 --disable-static-build
 --with-pqlib
 --without-pqlib
 --with-libpqlib
 --without-libpqlib
 --with-ms/libpqlib
 --without-ms/libpqlib

Gem files will remain installed in /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-preview3/gems/pg-0.9.0 for inspection.

Results logged to /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-preview3/gems/pg-0.9.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

I don't know what is the error...

Comment: `apt install postgresql-server-dev-all` for Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 731):

You need install the postgreSQL dev package with header of PostgreSQL

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: I did that as per your suggestion... the get the follwoing

Need to get 0B of archives. After unpacking 5378kB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
Writing extended state information... Done
(Reading database ... 166183 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing bison ...
Removing libnss3-dev ...
Removing libnspr4-dev ...
Removing libqt4-core ...
Removing libqt4-test ...
Removing libsqlite3-dev ...
Processing triggers for man-db ..

Comment: For those really new to Ubuntu as me, but really new use `sudo apt-get install aptitude` first :)

Comment: tried all sort of combinations. even after reinstalling postgres and libpq . no luck.. still the same problem

Comment: sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

works perfectly .... the nativ installer ofcourse needs the dev libs to compile the ruby "pg" gem.

Comment: For Cent/RedHat-flavored distros, the package you'll want is `yum install postgresql-devel`

Comment: I have a feeling this may not being working for some people due to their Ubuntu versions. This is failing for me on 13.04 with Postgres 9.1

Comment: Worked on debian as well ;)

Comment: Thank you!  I had a similar problem and your solution fixed it for me.  ;)

Answer (score 42):

After reading and thrashing around for 2 days, and trying many things found in other notes the following single line was the cure for me on Ubuntu Lucid 10.04 mixed with some Maverick packages and RVM  (ruby 1.9.2-p290,  rvm 1.10.2 rubygems 1.8.15, rails 3.0.1, postgres 8.4.10) :

```
gem install pg  --   --with-pg-lib=/usr/lib
```

the result:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...  
Successfully installed pg-0.13.1  
1 gem installed  
Installing ri documentation for pg-0.13.1...  
Installing RDoc documentation for pg-0.13.1...
```

{yea - finally success} !!
!note that the output from running pg_config lacks the item  -lpq   in the LIBS variable on my Ubuntu / Postresql install!!

and why the switch from   pq  to pg   in certain places -- confusing to newbie ??

the thing I still do not understand is the double set of  --   and  --with(option
but I'm way beyond my depth anyway

Comment: the '--' is commonly used to separate the parameters to the first command from the second, in this case, the configure script of the extmod

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing this solution. was stuck on this for a day. glad i encountered this post.

Answer (score 34):

In Ubuntu this works for me, I hope help you:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

and

```
gem install pg  --   --with-pg-lib=/usr/lib
```

Answer (score 30):

Installing libpq-dev did not work for me. I also needed to install build-essential

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev build-essential
```

Answer (score 30):

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 and running this command:

```
apt-get install libpq-dev
```

helped me - after that ran gem install pg -v "0.14.1", and all good now

Answer (score 27):

Need to add package

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

to install pg gem in RoR

Answer (score 16):

Simple solution for ubuntu users...

First uninstall all postgres packages, then run these commads...

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client libpq5 libpq-dev

# for rvm (single user)
mv ~/.rvm/usr/lib ~/.rvm/usr/lib_rvm 

# for rvm (multi-user)
mv /usr/local/rvm/usr/lib /usr/local/rvm/usr/lib_rvm

gem install pg  --   --with-pg-lib=/usr/lib
```

Then run 'bundle install'. Every thing will be fine. Have a good day!

Comment: If people are curious on how to remove all postgres packages, sudo apt-get remove --purge postgresql postgresql-9.3 (or whatever version of postgres you have).

Answer (score 13):

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-client libpq5 libpq-dev` then do `gem install pg`

Comment: Please add some context to your answer as to why this works. This also only works on a debian based system

Answer (score 9):

For .RVM users it will be better:

```
rvmsudo gem install pg -- --with-pg-lib=/usr/lib
```

it worked for me (after i saw jdupont version)

Answer (score 7):

If you have libpq-dev installed and are still having this problem it is likely due to conflicting versions of OpenSSL's libssl and friends - the Ubuntu system version in /usr/lib (which libpq is built against) and a second version RVM installed in $HOME/.rvm/usr/lib (or /usr/local/rvm/usr/lib if it's a system install). You can verify this by temporarily renaming $HOME/.rvm/usr/lib and seeing if "gem install pg" works.

To solve the problem have rvm rebuild using the system OpenSSL libraries (you may need to manually remove libssl.* and libcrypto.* from the rvm/usr/lib dir):

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr
```

This finally solved the problem for me on Ubunto 12.04.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! The newer the Ubuntu and the older the ruby build the more likely an OpenSSL mismatch will occur.

Comment: Nothing else worked except for this! Thank you so much @mike-blackwell. I had almost given up hope before you came to the rescue.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
```

You should install PG Database server in the first place to install clients. Afterwards, you install clients.

[See this blog post to know about setting up PostGresSQL for the first time for Ruby on Rails development.](http://www.shivabhusal.com/database/2017/07/11/configure-postgres-database-in-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 5):

This solved the problem for me on Ubuntu 12.04 after every suggestion here had failed.

```
rvmsudo gem install pg -v '0.12.2' -- --with-pg-lib=/usr/include/postgresql
```

Comment: My solution was almost the same; I'm using rbenv and what worked for me was: ` gem install pg -- --with-pg-lib=/usr/lib/postgresql/ --with-pg-include=/usr/include/postgresql/` ; I didn't need to specify a version.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to setup a Rails project in my freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04. I ran into the same issue while running bundle. Running

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is still having issues after trying all the answers on this page, the following (finally) worked:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
gem install pg
```

This was **after** doing everything else mentioned on this page.

postgresql 9.5.8
Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: This was what I needed on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to this problem is to install PostgreSQL using Homebrew/linuxbrew:

`brew install postgresql`

As a matter of habit I don't like to use sudo unless I have to.

Comment: Homebrew is only for Mac.

Comment: There's a Linux fork.

Comment: If you don't want to install the full PostgreSQL, the following worked for me: `brew install libpq && brew link libpq --force`

Answer (score 2):

For those trying to install Redmine, I missed `sudo apt-get install ruby-all-dev` after trying all of the above.

Initial error being `mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and tried a lot of different variants. After some tries I became able to `sudo gem install`, but still have problem to install it without sudo.
Finally I found a decission - reinstalling of rvm helped me. Probably it can save time somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get install ruby-dev` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) which works on Linux and macOS to install just the supporting libraries:

`brew install libpq`

then

`brew link libpq --force`

*(the `--force` option is required because it conflicts with the postgres formula.)*