# pg gem with Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to install the pg gem with a new rails app, but I keep receiving the same error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/arthur/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-lib=/usr/lib
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I've already tried everything from this question: [How to install PostgreSQL's pg gem on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116015/how-to-install-gem-pg-on-ubuntu)
but nothing really worked for me.

That's ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.2, by the way.

Thanks

Comment: Check this [link][1], hope it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209797/cant-find-the-postgresql-client-library-libpq

Comment: please append the ruby and rails version in your post.

Comment: Have you checked the mkmf.log as the output suggests? What does it say?

Comment: Rodrigo, it didnt helped.
stsd, just edited the post. Sorry about that.
davidrac, There is no mkmf.log file on any folder related to the pg gem. Any idea on where it should be located?

Comment: Check that the file `/usr/include/postgresql/libpq-fe.h` exists and exports the function `PQconnectdb`.

Comment: You need install postgresql in local development, run `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1` and try install `pg` gem again.

Answer (score 1):

Install postgresql 9 and then install your gem.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev
```

Now, run

```
gem install pg
```

and then

bundle install