# Installing the PostgreSQL gem with 'gem pq' fails with ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rubygems, pg

I am learning Ruby on Rails and trying to develop an application.
In my application I am trying to use the default **SQLite database in the Development Mode** and **PostgreSQL in the Production Mode**.
But I'm getting the following error while trying to install pg gem using: `gem install pg`

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 
    /home/tusharkhatiwada/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev
 for building a client-side application.
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev
 for building a client-side application.
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
 
Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/tusharkhatiwada/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
        --with-pg
        --without-pg
        --with-pg-config
        --without-pg-config
        --with-pg_config
        --without-pg_config
        --with-pg-dir
        --without-pg-dir
        --with-pg-include
        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
        --with-pg-lib
        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
 
 
Gem files will remain installed in /home/tusharkhatiwada/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4.0.0/g
ems/pg-0.17.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/tusharkhatiwada/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4.0.0/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext
/gem_make.out
```

After that I again tried with `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config= '/usr/bin/pg_config'`
and the following error is displayed:

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-config= /usr/bin/pg_config'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 
    /home/tusharkhatiwada/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config= /us
r/bin/pg_config
Using config values from 
sh: 1: : Permission denied
sh: 1: : Permission denied
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
 
Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/tusharkhatiwada/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
        --with-pg
        --without-pg
        --with-pg-config
        --with-pg-dir
        --without-pg-dir
        --with-pg-include
        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
        --with-pg-lib
        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
 
 
Gem files will remain installed in /home/tusharkhatiwada/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4.0.0/g
ems/pg-0.17.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/tusharkhatiwada/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4.0.0/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext
/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116015/how-to-install-gem-pg-on-ubuntu

Comment: @techvineet : It didn't solve my problem either.

Comment: There is some issue with your package manager. First, update your package manager by sudo apt-get update and then try to install these.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu try to install following lib file

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

and then gem install pg

worked for me.

Comment: I tried it but it also shows errors: 
`You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: comerr-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1c-4ubuntu8.1) but 1.0.1c-4ubuntu8 is to be installed
              Recommends: libssl-doc but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: sudo apt-get update                                                  sudo apt-get install build-essential ruby-dev libpcap-dev

Comment: This solution didn't work on my VM which was installed in cloud server  at [Koding](http://koding.com) but it did solve in my Laptop using Ubuntu.

Comment: This worked while upgrading gitlab from 5.1 to 6.0 using the turnkey linux version.

Comment: whenever i install postgresql i know that error will occur and i  will copy-paste this command to fix this problem by google-ing.

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada - This fixed it for me in the Koding dev environment: http://www.databasically.com/2010/03/05/installing-sqlite-headers-on-ubuntu-sqlite3-h-not-found/

Comment: How did you realise this is what was missing?

Comment: installing libpq-dev didnt work for me... but installing the libgmp-dev package did it.

Comment: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

for those who reached this by google search
if libpq-dev didnt work
or threw another errors
i hade the same problem
try upgrading your system
and get the ruby div-kit

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

then reboot
after this just try again

...

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev libpq-dev
```

and then

```
gem install pg
```