# Issue with the installation of gem 'pg' in Heroku - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, terminal

I'm trying to install ruby on rails on OSX for [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#write-your-app), for which I used [this tutorial](http://guides.railsgirls.com/install/#setup-for-os-x).  It seemed to install fine on the terminal, but after doing

```
$rails new myapp --database=postgresql
cd myapp
```

I did this

```
rails generate controller welcome
```

and got an error:

`Could not find gem 'spring (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run`bundle install`to install missing gems.`

And after following the instructions, I got

```
'An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.'
```

And then...

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        ...
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

A similar SO question said the problem was solved by updating XCode, but I don't think that's my problem.  If it wasn't already apparent, I'm not very experienced with the terminal or ruby, so I'm not sure how I can approach this issue.

EDIT:

new error message

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/mahireusufzai/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

...

```
/Users/mahireusufzai/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/mahireusufzai/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/mahireusufzai/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
    from extconf.rb:39:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mahireusufzai/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
```

Comment: Have you installed postgresql by brew? Also you mean OSX right?

Comment: @Mahir: Your solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364632/intalling-postgresql-gem-for-heroku-setup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the postgresql development libraries first. It's complaining libpq-fe.h is missing.

Try to solve as per the answer in the following post: [Rails: Error installing pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439207/rails-error-installing-pg-gem)

Comment: I think it fixed the issue... but I still have to check.  Is it okay if I manually installed postgres from the website before I did it via HomeBrew?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is still installation related, but the heroku instructions say to modify file `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb`, but the `app/views/welcome` folder is empty. (There is a welcome_controller.rb file in a separate path, but I'm not sure if this is the same thing)

Comment: The article says to create a new file and add lines. `Next we’ll add an index page. In file app/views/welcome/index.html.erb write:...`

Comment: Are you saying I have to manually create a .erb file?  I thought it should already be there

Comment: You have to manually create erb files for views against actions. If you had done `rails generate controller welcome index`, it would have been there. But I suppose you did `rails generate controller welcome` which means you need to create views manually for actions like index which you define later.

Comment: I haven't done anything in 2 weeks, and I'm trying rails generate controller and it doesn't work anymore

Comment: I posted the new error message above.  I also tried all your tips and it still has problems with pg

Answer (score 0):

try

```
yum install postgresql-devel
```

or

```
brew install postgresql
```

then `gem install pg` should work