# Postgresql Gem Not Installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, homebrew

I have been trying to run **bundle install** and I get the following error:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/fr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Upon following the instructions, I received the following error:

```
gem install pg -v '0.17.0'                                                    ⏎
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/fr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

I followed the instructions provided in a similar issue reported earlier. Please see [Installing PG gem - failure to build native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262312/installing-pg-gem-failure-to-build-native-extension)

But this has not helped as shown below:

```
brew install postgresql
Warning: Could not link postgresql. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link postgresql'

Possible conflicting files are:
==> /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4/bin/initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4: 2928 files, 38M


brew link postgresql
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4...
Warning: Could not link postgresql. Unlinking...
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4/share/man/man7/WITH.7
/usr/local/share/man/man7 is not writable. You should change its permissions.
```

My two concerns are:

1. How can I fix the issue related to the 'pg' gem?
2. To fix this issue, is it necessary to modify the read-write permissions of the files mentioned for the **brew link postgresql** output?

Comment: Has been answered multiple times before:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086073/rails-install-pg-cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem

Comment: please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/18864397/2518860

Comment: Check the permissions: `ls -ld /usr/local/Cellar` and open them up for writing:
`sudo chmod a+w /usr/local/Cellar` and try install again `brew install postgresql`

Comment: Hi @Monk_Code, I tried your suggestion. Upon checking the directory, I saw the below output:
`ls -ld /usr/local/Cellar
drwxrwxrwx  21 fr  wheel  714 Apr  7 10:49 /usr/local/Cellar`

Upon trying `brew install postgresql`, I saw the below output:
`Linking /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4...
Warning: Could not link postgresql. Unlinking...
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4/share/man/man7/WITH.7
/usr/local/share/man/man7 is not writable. You should change its permissions.`

Comment: Hi Everyone, I managed to get the issue solved. The main issue was the pg version - 0.17.0. I installed the latest Postgres.app and verified the version was 0.17.1 upon installation.

I then modified the gem file to simply `gem 'pg'` and ran `bundle update`.

Thanks to everyone for the suggestions and links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the issue solved. The main issue was the **pg version - 0.17.0**. I installed the latest Postgres.app and verified the version was **0.17.1** upon installation. I then modified the gem file to simply `gem 'pg'` and ran bundle update. Thanks to everyone for the suggestions and links.