# An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I just installed `Rails 4.0.2` and when creating a new app, in the bundle stage I get:

```
Installing pg (0.17.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/Users/Dee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
--with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You may want to add an osx tag.  The solution appears that it may be related specifically to your OS.

Comment: You might want to visit . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116015/how-to-install-gem-pg-on-ubuntu . Hope one of those solutions help

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I'm on a Mac running Mavericks. My solution was to install [Postgres](http://postgresapp.com).

And then in terminal install using homebrew with the configuration:

```bash
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config
```

**Note: This answer has been edited to use the `latest` symlink that is currently included in shipping versions of the Postgres app.**

Previous versions suggested:

```bash
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
```

Comment: Yup mine was in a different location as well. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Correct Bob, the version of postgresapp in which this worked for me, was Version 9.2.2.0, so they must have changed this location on the 9.3 release.

Comment: And now, as of 1/22/15 we're looking at the 9.4 release, it's good to see they're keeping it updated -- "gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config"

Comment: I was in a rush and missed the part of this answer that says "install using home-brew". This answer worked for me after I did `brew update; brew install postgres`

Comment: In your solution, please add the version, other the latest PG gem will install: `gem install pg -v '0.17.1' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config`

Comment: In my case (Linux Mint 17.1), install libpq-dev via apt-get made it.

Comment: This worked for me while trying to `bundle install` gems included in the Ruby Getting Started Heroku walkthrough: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#run-the-app-locally

Answer (score 188):

Some kind of error resported here [Installing PG gem on OS X - failure to build native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262312/installing-pg-gem-failure-to-build-native-extension)

To install dependencies on Ubuntu try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

and this

```
gem install pg
```

Comment: Im on a mac, what should I do?

Comment: Following the tutorial on railstutorial.org. This is what you need to do for Mint. Thanks.

Comment: railstutorial.org -- paid tutorial; any other ideas?

Comment: @Deekor If you're using Homebrew you can run `brew install postgresql`, then the `pg` gem should properly install. See [these docs](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew).

Answer (score 23):

app root:

1. brew update
2. brew install postgres
3. gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/**9.3.4**/bin/pg_config
4. bundle install
5. ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
6. launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
7. createuser -s -r postgres
8. rake db:create:all
9. rake db:migrate
10. rails s

NOTE: replace the version number in step 3 if needed.

Answer (score 11):

### Previously working answer with older version

I installed under mac OSX Mavericks, having the postgres app (Version 9.2.2.0 )  from [www.postgresapp.com](http://postgresapp.com) installed. The underlying problem was simpy that the since postgres was installed via the app, the configuration file resides on a location which is not the default one when installing it without postgressapp. so we need to tell gem where to find this file by:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This was my solution (OSX)

Comment: If this isnt working for anyone, for 9.3 the config file has moved - see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

If gem install pg fails, try the following command:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
```

... from the [PostgreSQL.app Documentation](http://postgresapp.com/documentation)

Comment: Since the official app recently changed names to "Postgres93.app", the command should be:

`env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config`

Comment: for me it worked with: 

`env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you do not have PostgreSQL installed. The `pg` gem requires some headers from PostgreSQL to compile native extension.

Comment: How about your Ruby/Bundler setup? You're using Mac OS X or Linux? and if you're using Mac OS X, you installed PostgreSQL via `homebrew` or PostgreSQL.app?

Comment: Im on a mac. I installed via the app

Comment: I have 0.17.0 installed. Any harm in using that with rails 4?

Comment: Then try running `bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config` and run `bundle` again. Adjust the config path if you install the app to `~/Application` rather than `/Application`

Answer (score 3):

I had to combine everything and use

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using something other than Postgres in development and Postgres in production only, you can add the pg gem to your gemfile like so...

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
end
```

Then use `bundle install --without production`

Answer (score 3):

For CentOS users:

```
sudo yum install postgresql-devel
```

and

```
gem install pg
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just set up a new Macbook Pro which was prebuilt with Catalina.

What worked for me:

1. Install the Postgres from here: https://postgresapp.com/
2. Add `export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"`to your `.zshenv`, since Z shell is now the default terminal.

Answer (score 1):

On mac this command worked for me.

`gem install pg -v '0.18.4' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`

Answer (score 0):

After installing Postgres I had to run the following command

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config
```

After this bundle install works great!

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The way I managed to get past that error was:

- cd to app folder and then set the ruby version locally. I'm using ruby 2.1.2.

> rbenv local 2.1.2

- instead of just running bundle install, install the gems in vendor/bundle

> bundle install --path vendor/bundle

This did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use sudo

```
sudo gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with Amazon and couldn't use apt-get.
For my worked:

```sh
    sudo yum install postgresql-devel
```

then:

```sh
    bundle install
```

and try again:

```sh
    rails serve
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed through Homebrew; `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config`. Works with Ruby 2.4.6 and pg 0.20.0.

Answer (score -2):

It works for me

```
rvm list gemsets
rvm use ruby-2.4.1
bundle
```

[image: error[![resolved with rvm use ruby]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8BF2.png)

Comment: You're not installing the `pg` gem here