# Google Compute Engine not reachable from selected external hosting (GoDaddy)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've developed a simple node.js application which lives in a customized Docker container (based on the node:carbon image).

The `docker run` command is:

```
docker run -p 8087:8087 --restart=on-failure -t --name=$RUN_NAME \ 
--env-file $DEV_ENV -d $CONTAINER_NAME:$CONTAINER_TAG
```

My webserver should be responding on port **8087** and it is from *inside* the container and from *outside* the vm by calling it from some other servers (not in Google Cloud).

**My problem is** that I should call it from my GoDaddy Linux hosting (curl call) and it's not reachable from there:

```
* About to connect() to x.x.x.x port 8087 (#0)
* Trying x.x.x.x... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
```

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Note: **I've opened the firewall for 
the 8087 port**.

Please help

Comment: Have you bind your container port to the host?. If not, as per [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/) document, the docker container need to binds its port with host. There is this simplified explanation provided [here](https://bobcares.com/blog/docker-port-expose/). I can see a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403341/boot2docker-access-webserver-as-localhost) as well.

Comment: Yes I did but thanks for pointing it out! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that you've checked from other external hosts, have you considered that GoDaddy might be blocking outbound traffic to port 8087 (possibly due to port-scanning or other bad behavior)?

You should be able to rule this out by starting a service on 8087 on a non GCP VM, and testing whether curl from GoDaddy is able to reach it.

Right now, from your description, it sounds like:

VM -> localhost -> VM : works
External -> internet -> VM: works
GoDaddy -> internet -> VM: fails

If other external hosts work, I'd start to suspect GoDaddy, assuming that you've ensured that your firewall rule is actually open to 0.0.0.0/0 and not some smaller subnet.

Comment: Your last conjecture is true: I've found out that GoDaddy's firewall allows only a few outbound ports. Their HelpDesk suggested using the 443 port...