# Bundle config for production only?

Tags: postgresql, centos, bundler

I'm getting an error when deploying my application to CentOS 6.x similar to the following: [An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754081/an-error-occurred-while-installing-pg-0-17-1-and-bundler-cannot-continue)

I've installed the required libs but am still getting the error.

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/exporter/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
    --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

From reading around it seems like I need to add --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config. I can easily do this by configuring bundler to install with the flag:

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config
```

But how can I do this without affecting my local dev environment? The /path/to/pg_config will be different for my production environment and my local dev environment.