# error ... gem install pg -v '0.18.4'`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems

New to coding and just installing Ruby on Rails and getting this error message when trying to create rails app: An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling. please help.

Comment: so what happens when you  run gem install pg -v '0.18.4' ?

Comment: ERROR:  Error installing pg:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: did you install postgresql?

Comment: You don't say what platform you're running on but if you're on Debian-based distributions (i.e. using `apt`), you need to install `libpq-dev` for the `pg` gem to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu, the answer from Mourndark's comment is pretty accurate.  Install libpq-dev and you will be ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the postgresql database.

Please check this question: [An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754081/an-error-occurred-while-installing-pg-0-17-1-and-bundler-cannot-continue)

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what environment you are working in, but this post should contain a majority of the possible fixes (you most likely need to install PostgreSQL locally) in addition to what Celso Martins posted: [Installing PG gem on OS X - failure to build native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262312/installing-pg-gem-on-os-x-failure-to-build-native-extension/19620569#19620569/)

Comment: am getting this Warning: postgresql-9.4.5_2 already installed, it's just not linked

Comment: Would you mind posting the entire output? @BrendanMosweu

Comment: An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: What method did you use to install PostgreSQL? MacPorts? @BrendanMosweu

Comment: PostgreSQL
You can install PostgreSQL server and client from Homebrew:

brew install postgresql
Once this command is finished, it gives you a couple commands to run. Follow the instructions and run them:

# To have launchd start postgresql at login:
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents

# Then to load postgresql now:
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
By default the postgresql user is your current OS X username with no password. For example, my OS X user is named chris so I can login to postgresql with that username.

Comment: I also tried to fix the problem by installing using Graphical installer

Comment: The location of pg_config is likely the issue. Check these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625487/impossible-to-install-pg-gem-on-my-mac-with-mavericks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234960/gem-install-pg-with-pg-config-works-bundle-fails @BrendanMosweu

Answer (score 0):

I executed
`sudo apt-get remove libpq5` and
`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` and after `bundle install`