# Rails bundle install has issues with postgres gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I've been running into issues with pg in my Rails gem. When I try to..

```
$ bundle install
```

..my terminal returns..

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.21.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.21.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

My gemfile includes this:

```
group :production, :default do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

The exercise I am doing is to deploy my Rails app in Heroku, and it works. The idea is that I do not install postgres locally.

This is my Github repo, if it helps: https://github.com/cyqurayte/Rails1

Comment: On what platform are you? Is there a more specific error message?
Maybe it's something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116015/how-to-install-postgresqls-pg-gem-on-ubuntu

Comment: Heroku.
I have sqlite3 for dev environment and postgres for production environment on heroku

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is that I do not install postgres locally.

I don't think it's possible to install this gem without having postgres already installed and updated

The reason this works on heroku is that the environment there already has postgres installed

Comment: locally its supposed to be sqlite3, on heroku postgres