# gem install pg for ruby on rails, error message: lack of necessary libraries and/or headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu, rubygems

I am new to ruby and encounter when I was trying to `gem install pg` and get this problem

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-lib=/usr/lib'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/chensiyuan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-pg
--without-pg
--enable-windows-cross
--disable-windows-cross
--with-pg-config
--without-pg-config
--with-pg_config
--without-pg_config
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
```

I have checked the log file and it shows like this

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wmisleading-indentation'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wimplicit-fallthrough=0'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wduplicated-cond'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wrestrict'
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

I have already installed the postgresql by

`sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper`

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

`brew install postgresql`

That's what I have done for this problem after I searched other notes. Can someone please help me out here? I have checked all the possible duplicate and the above commmands are from those answers. However, my ubuntu still complains about the same issues.

Comment: Which files are missing? Show error message please

Comment: Do you have a full gcc installation? What does `gcc --version` say when you run it from the command line?

Comment: When I typed gcc --version, it says `gcc (Homebrew gcc 5.5.0_4) 5.5.0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install PostgreSQL's pg gem on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116015/how-to-install-postgresqls-pg-gem-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I have checked this question as you can see all the commands in this possible duplicates are already tried by me.

Answer (score 1):

If your `brew install postgresql` was installed successfully installed, then try `bundle install` in the ruby app again.